# Does anyone know how to fix "No SIM card/Emergency calls only" error on Sprint Note 3 CM12.1?

Tags: cyanogenmod

I had this smartphone working just a few days ago (on CM12.1) but because I changed the phone number on it I had to flash it back to the stock firmware to run the PRL & Profile update. Now that I've flashed CM12.1 back on it the only thing not working is the phone/mobile data. I read on the XDE website that I need to flash a NH7 modem, but the only link on that page is dead.... I believe I flashed the modem the last time I rooted the phone and installed CM12 but that's been over a year ago and I didn't keep a copy of it on my PC. I briefly looked around on google but haven't been able to find any viable solution. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my custom Virgin Mobile XT1548 MotoG3 (Osprey). Thing is, CM is more geared for phones that are CDMA. It'll break your SIM card every time you flash if you aren't CDMA. Thankfully, I still have data, but no voice. So I use a VoIP number to make my calls

Comment: One should really only flash CM onto a phone they no longer care for, or if its a development phone. Flashing it onto my main phone was a huge mistake.

Comment: I am on Sprint, and like I mentioned, already had CM12.1 working fully on the same smartphone just two days ago, so I know it's possible.

Comment: However, I would look up APNs for your carrier to try and at least get your data back.

Comment: Look up your Access Point Names for Sprint and manually input it to make your SIM working as much as possible.

Comment: Apparently you're not hearing me. It's not "as much as possible", it can work 100% because it was two days ago (on CM12.1). It wasn't until I changed the phone number (from another Sprint phone) to this phone that it stopped working. Everything else is the same. Same phone, same ROM. It is a valid link to a NH7 modem that I need, nothing else. I just haven't been able to find one anywhere online. You would think that thousands of people would have this same issue and the file would be floating around everywhere, but for some reason it's not.